# clojure laziness: prevent unneded mapcat results to realize

Tags: clojure, lazy-evaluation

Consider a query function q that returns, with a delay, some (let say ten) results.

Delay function:

```
(defn dlay [x]
  (do
    (Thread/sleep 1500)
    x))
```

Query function:

```
(defn q [pg]
  (lazy-seq
   (let [a [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ]]
     (println "q")
     (map #(+ (* pg 10) %) (dlay a)))))
```

Wanted behaviour:
I would like to produce an infinite lazy sequence such that when I take a value only needed computations are evaluated

Wrong but explicative example:

```
(drop 29 (take 30 (mapcat q (range))))
```

If I'm not wrong, it needs to evaluate every sequence because it really doesn't now how long the sequences will be.

How would you obtain the correct behaviour?

My attempt to correct this behaviour:

```
(defn getq [coll n]
  (nth 
   (nth coll (quot n 10))
   (mod n 10)))

(defn results-seq []
  (let [a (map q (range))]
    (map (partial getq a)
         (iterate inc 0)))) ; using iterate instead of range, this way i don't have a chunked sequence
```

But

```
(drop 43 (take 44 (results-seq)))
```

still realizes the "unneeded" `q` sequences.

Now, I verified that `a` is lazy, iterate and map should produce lazy sequences, so the problem must be with `getq`. But I can't understand really how it breaks my laziness...perhaps does `nth` realize things while walking through a sequence? If this would be true, is there a viable alternative in this case or my solution suffers from bad design?

Comment: I'm not following. Are you expecting that `(drop 43 (take 44 (some-seq))` would only realize the 44th element? In that case no, `(take 44 ...)` will realize 44 elements of which all but one is dropped by `(drop 43 ...)`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm expecting this for a lazy sequence. A working example in this case could be `(drop 43 (take 44 (map q (range))))`, it realizes the function q only one time, right?

Comment: No, as @ShannonSeverance said, your function `q` will be called 44 times. A sequence is not a random access collection. For instance, `(nth (iterate inc 10) 5)` will give `15` and `inc` has been called 5 times, even if `iterate` yields a lazy sequence. A sequence is a logical list abstraction, explained [here](http://clojure.org/sequences). If you look at the source for `drop`, you'll see that all dropped element are consumed until the first non-dropped.